# Distorted output while reading in the fast appending logs using Tail in Unix

Tags: unix, tail, file-read

I am using a `tail` function to read close to 460 log files which keep appending all at the same time. The data I am trying to read is byte separated fixed width.Please find below the command I use:

```
find ###Directory### -mmin -2  -type f -name FileNameString*.log | xargs tail -qf -n -1
```

The expected format of log files is given below:

```
KS0A2018020723594007G58P5CNSSHAGPRGGWS G      NH 0962201803061535PEK  HND  C 999   9 9CC91 990C 900 99
KS0A2018020723594007G58P5CNSSHAGPRGGWS G      NH 5702201803060910PEK  NRT  C 444   0 4  0  40   00  44
```

but the format I see in the output is as below:

```
KS0A2018020723594912V1KY7USSCNTNPRAAPI P      AA 3735201802111632IAH  OR3903G7YI0HKSQUNAPRAAPI P      AA 1583201812241935DEN  DFW  P 7 7  777777777 7 7  7  7
KS0A2018020723593952G56SCKRSGKORPRGFLCNG      AZ 0758201809301515FCO  ICN  P07100007017070010 00 7007
```

The `tail` function is distorting the way files are being read.
Any guidance in reading the format right using tail or any equivalent command will greatly help.

Answer (score 1):

You need the `-z` option for `tail`.

```
$ find /path/to/ -mmin -2  -type f -name FileNameString*.log | xargs tail -qf -z -n -1
```

> ```
>    -z, --zero-terminated
>           line delimiter is NUL, not newline
> ```

Better to use, `-exec` for `find`

```
$ find /path/to/ -mmin -2 -type f -name "FileNameString*.log"  -exec tail -qf -z -n -1 {} \+
```

Comment: Hi iamauser, I have executed the tail with -z and --zero-terminated option. However, tail does not recognize the -z option. When I do a tail --help, it does not show -z as an option. As far as using -exec goes, it produces the same output. Any more suggestions are greately appreciated.

Comment: You need to specify either `-z` or `--zero-terminated`, they are same. Did it work for you ?

Comment: I used -z once it did not work. Then I tried --zero-terminated. Unfortunately it did not work

Answer (score 0):

If we do an Xargs without assigning arguments to the Xargs, there will always be distortion in the output (as it tends to distort the line formation).
So,

```
find ###Directory### -mmin -2  -type f -name FileNameString*.log | xargs tail -qf -n -1
```

will always lead to distorted output as there is no controlled way to read in or write the output.

However, if we can pass the input variables to Xargs in a controlled manner by using -I, it was functioning well. In my case,

```
find ###Directory### -mmin -2  -type f -name FileNameString*.log | xargs -I% tail % -qf -n -1
```

produced the output format I expected. However, this can be a on the slower side of execution if the variable list to be passed to Xargs is lengthy.